# Django 1.8 creates migration but nothing has changed

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I am having a migration issue with a Django 1.8.2 application. I'm using two models, `Product` and `Fee`. `Product` recently had a change to its `unique_together` field. `Fee` had no changes to its `unique_together` field. When I run `./manage.py makemigrations` I get a file with two changes:

```
operations = [
    migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
        name='fee',
        unique_together=set([('product', 'fee_type', 'content_type', 'object_id', 'activation_date')]),
    ),
    migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
        name='product',
        unique_together=set([('producer', 'product_type', 'term')]),
    ),
]
```

You'll notice it is changing the unique together constraint for `Product`, which is fine. But then it is also doing it for `Fee`. That causes and error because that unique together constraint already exists in the database. The error is `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "product_fee_product_id_7b033c697cde4424_uniq" already exists`

Every time I run `./manage.py makemigrations` I get the `AlterUniqueTogether` stuff for the `Fee` model, even if I simply comment it out or remove it from the file with both migrations. How can I prevent `makemigrations` from detecting this nonexistent change?

Comment: have you tried `flush` and `reset`

Comment: I have not, no. I don't think I'm familiar with those commands.

Comment: `flush` flushes data in your db, `reset` reset the tables.

Comment: I don't think I can `flush` because that will completely remove all the data in the tables. And I don't see a `reset` command in the docs.

Comment: if  you can't `flush` then you most like will not `reset`. I think the problem is with proudct id `7b033c697cde4424`. try removing or renaming that item

Comment: I've done a `flush` locally. When I run `makemigrations` I still get a migration for `Fee`. Also, the `reset` command was removed several Django versions ago.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a migration that only alters the unique together for the `Fee` model, and then use the `--fake` option to apply it

```
./manage.py migrate yourapp 00XX_your_migration --fake
```

After you've faked the migration, the change should not be included in any new migrations you create.