# Django 1.8 makemigration generates new migration whith no changes in model

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm using  Django (1.8.4) and postgress, and I have a problem with makemigrations.
It generates new migrations randomly, and thesecontain changes already applied in my db.

My model:

```
   class GalleryType(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        description = models.TextField()
        slug = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
        fecha_modificacion = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class GalleryExtended(models.Model):
        # Link back to Photologue's Gallery model.
        gallery = models.OneToOneField(Gallery, related_name='extended')
        order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        type = models.ForeignKey(to='GalleryType', related_name='gallerytype',        default=DEFAUTL_GALLERY_TYPE_ID)
        lugar_evento = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

when I run "python manage.py makemigrations"
I get a migration with

```
migrations.AlterField(
    model_name='galleryextended',
    name='type',
    field=models.ForeignKey(default=1, to='photogallery.GalleryType', related_name='gallerytype'),
),
```

but this change is allready aplied in my db!!

```
CREATE TABLE photogallery_galleryextended
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  "order" integer NOT NULL,
  gallery_id integer NOT NULL,
  type_id integer NOT NULL,
  lugar_evento character varying(150),
  CONSTRAINT photogallery_galleryextended_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT photoga_type_id_64931acb553c985b_fk_photogallery_gallerytype_id FOREIGN KEY (type_id)
      REFERENCES photogallery_gallerytype (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
  CONSTRAINT photogalle_gallery_id_4fb0cbc52e5218b7_fk_photologue_gallery_id FOREIGN KEY (gallery_id)
      REFERENCES photologue_gallery (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
  CONSTRAINT photogallery_galleryextended_gallery_id_key UNIQUE (gallery_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE photogallery_galleryextended
  OWNER TO myuser;
```

If I run the command python manage.py makemigrations again:

```
************************************************************************
********* 2015-10-15 17:53:04 RUN AT : local **** Site:1 *********
No changes detected
```

If I run it once again without changing nothing at all:

```
************************************************************************
********* 2015-10-15 17:53:18 RUN AT : local **** Site:1 *********
Migrations for 'photogallery':
  0022_auto_20151015_1753.py:
    - Alter field type on galleryextended
```

The new migration 0022_auto_20151015_1753.py contains:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('photogallery', '0021_auto_20151015_1748'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='galleryextended',
            name='type',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default=1, to='photogallery.GalleryType',
            related_name='gallerytype'),
        ),
    ]
```

If i continue reapeating the "python manage.py makemigrations" command I get more migrations, the only thing changing is the order of the elements of ForeignKey

```
operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='galleryextended',
        name='type',
        field=models.ForeignKey(to='photogallery.GalleryType', related_name='gallerytype', default=1),
    ),
]
operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='galleryextended',
        name='type',
        field=models.ForeignKey(to='photogallery.GalleryType', default=1, related_name='gallerytype'),
    ),
]
operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='galleryextended',
        name='type',
        field=models.ForeignKey(related_name='gallerytype', default=1, to='photogallery.GalleryType'),
    ),
]
```

Related to:

[Django 1.8 creates migration but nothing has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376534/django-1-8-creates-migration-but-nothing-has-changed)

Hi, thanks for the reply, I have tried

```
>>> from apps.photogallery.models import GalleryExtended
>>> GalleryExtended._meta.get_field('type').deconstruct()
('type', 'django.db.models.ForeignKey', [], {'related_name': 'gallerytype', 'default': 1, 'to': 'photogallery.GalleryType'})
>>> GalleryExtended._meta.get_field('type').deconstruct()
('type', 'django.db.models.ForeignKey', [], {'related_name': 'gallerytype', 'default': 1, 'to': 'photogallery.GalleryType'})
>>> GalleryExtended._meta.get_field('type').deconstruct()
('type', 'django.db.models.ForeignKey', [], {'related_name': 'gallerytype', 'default': 1, 'to': 'photogallery.GalleryType'})
>>> GalleryExtended._meta.get_field('type').deconstruct()
('type', 'django.db.models.ForeignKey', [], {'related_name': 'gallerytype', 'default': 1, 'to': 'photogallery.GalleryType'})

>>> from django.db.migrations.autodetector import MigrationAutodetector
>>> ma = MigrationAutodetector(None,None) ;
>>> ma.deep_deconstruct(GalleryExtended._meta.get_field('type'))
('django.db.models.ForeignKey', [], {'related_name': 'gallerytype', 'default': 1, 'to': 'photogallery.GalleryType'})
>>>
```

But it continues to genereate these unnecesary mirations when I exit the shell and makemigrtions

Comment: I have a debugging idea. What defines if field versions are different is a comparison of their `deconstruct`ed versions. So could you try running  `GalleryExtended._meta.get_field('type').deconstruct()` in  `manage.py shell` a couple of times to see what changes?

Comment: Actually, better try `django.db.migrations.autodetector.MigrationAutodetector.deep_deconstruct()` on your field. Something like `ma = MigrationAutodetector(None,None) ; ma.deep_deconstruct(GalleryExtended._meta.get_field('type'))` should do.

Comment: Also, could you add `DEFAUTL_GALLERY_TYPE_ID` definition to your code?

Comment: Hi DEFAUTL_GALLERY_TYPE_ID=1 in my settings.

Comment: @"Jose Arrecio" And for the `deconstruct`?

Comment: I think actually that it's better to try this same thing on a normal and historical version for the last migration. Maybe there will be some differences.

Comment: I'll look how can this can be done.

Comment: FYI https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.4/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py#L829

Comment: Thank you bicycle repairman!

Comment: You can try overriding the `makemigrations` command and adding a `print` in `MigrationAutodetector` where it compares the results of `deep_deconstruct`s and run `makemigrations`. Replace the `MigrationAutodetector` import in `django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py` with your version.

Comment: After `old_field_dec = self.deep_deconstruct(old_field) new_field_dec = self.deep_deconstruct(new_field)`

Comment: We had/have the same problem when setting the default for a datetime field to a value instead of a callable (e.g. `default=datetime.now()` instead of `default=datetime.now`). My guess is if you wrap your default on the FK to a callable, like a lambda, you will need one more migration, then after that everything should be fine.

Comment: Django cannot serialize lambdas